# Keep getting "DOWNSTREAM_SERVICE_RETURNED_ERROR" error message while making graphql requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests, graphql

I'm trying to make a POST request using graphql. I'm making another POST request using graphql to the same website, and it works. However, for this one it doesn't.

This is my code :

```
cookies = {
    'cesc': '^%^7B^%^22lpe^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22ad5db897-6d75-4288-b67c-9b5ff512f0cf^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22marketingClick^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22false^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22lmc^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22BRAND.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22hitNumber^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^227^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22amc^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22BRAND.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22visitNumber^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^2244^%^22^%^2C1688324647088^%^5D^%^2C^%^22ape^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22ad5db897-6d75-4288-b67c-9b5ff512f0cf^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22cidVisit^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22Brand.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22entryPage^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22Homepage^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22cid^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22Brand.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688140309957^%^5D^%^7D',
    'MC1': 'GUID=1dd95f7adb420e35fe1d9f06311e91c3',
    'DUAID': '1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3',
    'ha-device-id': '1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3',
    'hav': '1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3',
    'cto_bundle': 'YQZalV8wdWl0d2liWld3dU5weWY4WXM1VmtyQmsxRUJydElkcFYxNGRqZElzRm8yTjQ0WU0lMkJVelVPQVo1OHkycDBCelJpMG9iU21JTWg4enhzTXlVNSUyQkdvYmlUVzFlZm5LaHNMYlRuR3dHZmJTSWd4SzJmZnFMVFR4NHAzRDlSbjdVY1c',
    'xdid': 'f07ebeb5-87e1-449c-b2a3-65b19c9f1b8b^|1676406244^|vrbo.com',
    'edge-polyfill-location': 'city^%^3DVANCOUVER^%^2C^%^20region^%^3DBC^%^2C^%^20country^%^3DCA^%^2C^%^20lat^%^3D49.25^%^2C^%^20lng^%^3D-123.13^%^2C^%^20asn^%^3D147049^%^2C^%^20city^%^3DVANCOUVER^%^2C^%^20region^%^3DBC^%^2C^%^20country^%^3DCA^%^2C^%^20lat^%^3D49.25^%^2C^%^20lng^%^3D-123.13^%^2C^%^20asn^%^3D147049',
    'edge-polyfill-device-classification': '10',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.221959039.1677684145',
    'tracker_device': '56215dc5-9fe6-4813-9ca5-a3e34cc98413',
    'ha-trip-prst': '^%^7B^%^22arrival^%^22^%^3A^%^22^%^22^%^2C^%^22departure^%^22^%^3A^%^22^%^22^%^2C^%^22numberOfAdults^%^22^%^3A1^%^2C^%^22numberOfChildren^%^22^%^3A0^%^2C^%^22petIncluded^%^22^%^3Afalse^%^7D',
    'linfo': 'v.4,^|0^|0^|255^|1^|0^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|1033^|0^|0^|^|0^|0^|0^|-1^|-1',
    'CRQS': 't^|9001`s^|9001001`l^|en_US`c^|USD',
    'currency': 'USD',
    '_cls_v': '31709e1e-eed2-4d45-ac00-2e0dd5e9e1d3',
    'OIP': 'ccpa^|1',
    'hav': '1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3',
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.26939620.1684766343',
    'QuantumMetricUserID': 'adfd6702ee31dae55778356a9b661fef',
    'AMCV_C00802BE5330A8350A490D4C^%^40AdobeOrg': '1585540135^%^7CMCIDTS^%^7C19541^%^7CMCMID^%^7C61485540774101176164512442867721946031^%^7CMCAID^%^7CNONE^%^7CMCOPTOUT-1688331845s^%^7CNONE^%^7CMCAAMLH-1688929445^%^7C7^%^7CMCAAMB-1688929445^%^7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI^%^7CvVersion^%^7C4.4.0^%^7CMCCIDH^%^7C-2034012538',
    'aspp': 'v.1,0^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|',
    '_tq_id.TV-8181636390-1.1968': '778916bb909d0071.1685728938.0.1688324650..',
    'EG_SESSIONTOKEN': 'FzLOVnI55XeEEs43AXOams8TyUvlfniYxew_mCZE1Ww:cVASiQ3OV_nEobIvC3rLa-csdtgjDX3yoZPsG7AC_8A',
    'tpid': 'v.1,9001',
    'has': '219ff0b0-ef3e-1381-fd29-737f40a29a30',
    'eg_ppid': '9cae9ff2-769c-47fd-b557-b840df5cee61',
    '219ff0b0-ef3e-1381-fd29-737f40a29a30SL': '1',
    'hal': 'ga=1&ua=1&si=1&ui=1&vi=1&pr=0',
    '219ff0b0-ef3e-1381-fd29-737f40a29a30UAL': '1',
    'eu-site': '0',
    'site': 'vrbo',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.414352333.1688316408',
    'ln_or': 'eyIxMjI2OTUzIjoiZCJ9',
    'ak_bmsc': '1D22DD68E291DD1FABE98CB591A85C2F~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQFQQ1FxJbvd6IAQAAyjrGFxSF8XxQO4ivs8jVnZnRaHfnGwhA9/CwHUt52JJvI6D31WrMosgF4GAhiHzaS/hnvfganooFph7kASCiN77Qw5kf3stq+UkRNhzXE+pCRPhuru/ZTJ46q4AU5v/qXGUuqLJxS1Fv6tzkpCGNiajR0KhjTGnIfFK/on2KvoqMZURDLIjxSyTbN6IwpXEno3fkkJDZ9YfEta+X0VwCFv82SRaE9rbEVavx5E/RsNOlpuz35tKRb6DKn/pvnBrrAgTht4QUQeFh3WC2hRu8JBQfUADjC5I84h3Vtw9wEoAb7iIzeaYRTzXbK7xaaR6nOavhJ7EMsYSFfx0Ws366CheLZEkSierjxC5755U7jwpiC81Q0phy1qlwdg==',
    'CRQSS': 'e^|1',
    'iEAPID': '1',
    'HMS': '065ac9a0-d3b5-429a-a2f0-5d6df914e9ab',
    'bm_sv': '39A35AB67AC2DF0775F60CE40C40FC38~YAAQDTqWuCoM//uIAQAAWQf/FxSgJk7b6E6ZfpBM9JFhPa/bhIPeMnggban2UgHf2/pOmHeqE7jrrXhuYP8Y9MDU5gS5/x0kvK35hbCuMv9D95t/cf7s8e4/fPKx0z4ibVLd4ldjt6vJkcn2zbYULmdHcqPTYeVAU3GPonpNFyJ8D8cQrCoCBtP1ptEINwl5XhYJNCHsZDTe6Lt/jmNguGC6PrhURaCxikjbaEnxLYNUhorK0Ir7SWLeInb66vw=~1',
    's_ppn': 'page.Hotels.Infosite.Information',
    's_ppv': '^%^5B^%^5BB^%^5D^%^5D',
    's_ips': '1',
    's_tp': '6763',
    'session_id': '065ac9a0-d3b5-429a-a2f0-5d6df914e9ab',
    'page_name': 'page.Hotels.Infosite.Information',
    'JSESSIONID': '6258FA29DD77610A2D64F96429BA6F35',
    '_dd_s': 'rum=0&expire=1688325630781',
    'AWSELB': 'D79B53F10ADCF9DDDF09C7B84896C09A6222EC2F5D58CCE84F5EE42C490A9D04E32FD39684A6FC87939663FD3254F5F91BACAFF5FECDCF6D09CE75717B929883FAFE61E346',
    'AWSELBCORS': 'D79B53F10ADCF9DDDF09C7B84896C09A6222EC2F5D58CCE84F5EE42C490A9D04E32FD39684A6FC87939663FD3254F5F91BACAFF5FECDCF6D09CE75717B929883FAFE61E346',
    'AMCVS_C00802BE5330A8350A490D4C^%^40AdobeOrg': '1',
    '_uetsid': '01c1eb4018f811ee9a304164c43be877',
    '_uetvid': '851b59f0aca511edbc4f73c5057866b2',
    'MC1': 'GUID=1dd95f7adb420e35fe1d9f06311e91c3',
    'DUAID': '1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3',
    'MC1': 'GUID=1dd95f7adb420e35fe1d9f06311e91c3',
    'DUAID': '1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.vrbo.com/9807926ha?adults=1&bedroom_count_gt=&chain=&chkin=8^%^2F21^%^2F2023&chkout=8^%^2F28^%^2F2023&dateSelectedByUser=false&daysInFuture=&destination=&endDate=8^%^2F28^%^2F2023&expediaPropertyId=92311994&group=&guestRating=&highlightedPropertyId=&hotelName=&latLong=&misId=&neighborhood=&petsIncluded=false&poi=&pricing_group=&pwa_ts=1688324650353&referrerUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudnJiby5jb20vSG90ZWwtU2VhcmNo&regionId=&rm1=a1&roomIndex=&selected=&selectedRatePlan=00004b1d3b77896d44c1ae912ad9fc7ead3e&selectedRoomType=92311994&sort=RECOMMENDED&startDate=8^%^2F21^%^2F2023&stayLength=&theme=&us_bathroom_count_gt=&useRewards=true&userIntent=&vacationRentalsOnly=false&x_pwa=1',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'client-info': 'shopping-pwa,a8b562b608b5bb6666ddf94403b50d3fe34103ce,us-east-1',
    'x-page-id': 'page.Hotels.Infosite.Information,H,30',
    'Origin': 'https://www.vrbo.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # 'Cookie': 'cesc=^%^7B^%^22lpe^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22ad5db897-6d75-4288-b67c-9b5ff512f0cf^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22marketingClick^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22false^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22lmc^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22BRAND.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22hitNumber^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^227^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22amc^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22BRAND.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22visitNumber^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^2244^%^22^%^2C1688324647088^%^5D^%^2C^%^22ape^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22ad5db897-6d75-4288-b67c-9b5ff512f0cf^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22cidVisit^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22Brand.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22entryPage^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22Homepage^%^22^%^2C1688324736846^%^5D^%^2C^%^22cid^%^22^%^3A^%^5B^%^22Brand.DTI^%^22^%^2C1688140309957^%^5D^%^7D; MC1=GUID=1dd95f7adb420e35fe1d9f06311e91c3; DUAID=1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3; ha-device-id=1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3; hav=1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3; cto_bundle=YQZalV8wdWl0d2liWld3dU5weWY4WXM1VmtyQmsxRUJydElkcFYxNGRqZElzRm8yTjQ0WU0lMkJVelVPQVo1OHkycDBCelJpMG9iU21JTWg4enhzTXlVNSUyQkdvYmlUVzFlZm5LaHNMYlRuR3dHZmJTSWd4SzJmZnFMVFR4NHAzRDlSbjdVY1c; xdid=f07ebeb5-87e1-449c-b2a3-65b19c9f1b8b^|1676406244^|vrbo.com; edge-polyfill-location=city^%^3DVANCOUVER^%^2C^%^20region^%^3DBC^%^2C^%^20country^%^3DCA^%^2C^%^20lat^%^3D49.25^%^2C^%^20lng^%^3D-123.13^%^2C^%^20asn^%^3D147049^%^2C^%^20city^%^3DVANCOUVER^%^2C^%^20region^%^3DBC^%^2C^%^20country^%^3DCA^%^2C^%^20lat^%^3D49.25^%^2C^%^20lng^%^3D-123.13^%^2C^%^20asn^%^3D147049; edge-polyfill-device-classification=10; _ga=GA1.2.221959039.1677684145; tracker_device=56215dc5-9fe6-4813-9ca5-a3e34cc98413; ha-trip-prst=^%^7B^%^22arrival^%^22^%^3A^%^22^%^22^%^2C^%^22departure^%^22^%^3A^%^22^%^22^%^2C^%^22numberOfAdults^%^22^%^3A1^%^2C^%^22numberOfChildren^%^22^%^3A0^%^2C^%^22petIncluded^%^22^%^3Afalse^%^7D; linfo=v.4,^|0^|0^|255^|1^|0^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|1033^|0^|0^|^|0^|0^|0^|-1^|-1; CRQS=t^|9001`s^|9001001`l^|en_US`c^|USD; currency=USD; _cls_v=31709e1e-eed2-4d45-ac00-2e0dd5e9e1d3; OIP=ccpa^|1; hav=1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3; _gcl_au=1.1.26939620.1684766343; QuantumMetricUserID=adfd6702ee31dae55778356a9b661fef; AMCV_C00802BE5330A8350A490D4C^%^40AdobeOrg=1585540135^%^7CMCIDTS^%^7C19541^%^7CMCMID^%^7C61485540774101176164512442867721946031^%^7CMCAID^%^7CNONE^%^7CMCOPTOUT-1688331845s^%^7CNONE^%^7CMCAAMLH-1688929445^%^7C7^%^7CMCAAMB-1688929445^%^7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI^%^7CvVersion^%^7C4.4.0^%^7CMCCIDH^%^7C-2034012538; aspp=v.1,0^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|; _tq_id.TV-8181636390-1.1968=778916bb909d0071.1685728938.0.1688324650..; EG_SESSIONTOKEN=FzLOVnI55XeEEs43AXOams8TyUvlfniYxew_mCZE1Ww:cVASiQ3OV_nEobIvC3rLa-csdtgjDX3yoZPsG7AC_8A; tpid=v.1,9001; has=219ff0b0-ef3e-1381-fd29-737f40a29a30; eg_ppid=9cae9ff2-769c-47fd-b557-b840df5cee61; 219ff0b0-ef3e-1381-fd29-737f40a29a30SL=1; hal=ga=1&ua=1&si=1&ui=1&vi=1&pr=0; 219ff0b0-ef3e-1381-fd29-737f40a29a30UAL=1; eu-site=0; site=vrbo; _gid=GA1.2.414352333.1688316408; ln_or=eyIxMjI2OTUzIjoiZCJ9; ak_bmsc=1D22DD68E291DD1FABE98CB591A85C2F~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQFQQ1FxJbvd6IAQAAyjrGFxSF8XxQO4ivs8jVnZnRaHfnGwhA9/CwHUt52JJvI6D31WrMosgF4GAhiHzaS/hnvfganooFph7kASCiN77Qw5kf3stq+UkRNhzXE+pCRPhuru/ZTJ46q4AU5v/qXGUuqLJxS1Fv6tzkpCGNiajR0KhjTGnIfFK/on2KvoqMZURDLIjxSyTbN6IwpXEno3fkkJDZ9YfEta+X0VwCFv82SRaE9rbEVavx5E/RsNOlpuz35tKRb6DKn/pvnBrrAgTht4QUQeFh3WC2hRu8JBQfUADjC5I84h3Vtw9wEoAb7iIzeaYRTzXbK7xaaR6nOavhJ7EMsYSFfx0Ws366CheLZEkSierjxC5755U7jwpiC81Q0phy1qlwdg==; CRQSS=e^|1; iEAPID=1; HMS=065ac9a0-d3b5-429a-a2f0-5d6df914e9ab; bm_sv=39A35AB67AC2DF0775F60CE40C40FC38~YAAQDTqWuCoM//uIAQAAWQf/FxSgJk7b6E6ZfpBM9JFhPa/bhIPeMnggban2UgHf2/pOmHeqE7jrrXhuYP8Y9MDU5gS5/x0kvK35hbCuMv9D95t/cf7s8e4/fPKx0z4ibVLd4ldjt6vJkcn2zbYULmdHcqPTYeVAU3GPonpNFyJ8D8cQrCoCBtP1ptEINwl5XhYJNCHsZDTe6Lt/jmNguGC6PrhURaCxikjbaEnxLYNUhorK0Ir7SWLeInb66vw=~1; s_ppn=page.Hotels.Infosite.Information; s_ppv=^%^5B^%^5BB^%^5D^%^5D; s_ips=1; s_tp=6763; session_id=065ac9a0-d3b5-429a-a2f0-5d6df914e9ab; page_name=page.Hotels.Infosite.Information; JSESSIONID=6258FA29DD77610A2D64F96429BA6F35; _dd_s=rum=0&expire=1688325630781; AWSELB=D79B53F10ADCF9DDDF09C7B84896C09A6222EC2F5D58CCE84F5EE42C490A9D04E32FD39684A6FC87939663FD3254F5F91BACAFF5FECDCF6D09CE75717B929883FAFE61E346; AWSELBCORS=D79B53F10ADCF9DDDF09C7B84896C09A6222EC2F5D58CCE84F5EE42C490A9D04E32FD39684A6FC87939663FD3254F5F91BACAFF5FECDCF6D09CE75717B929883FAFE61E346; AMCVS_C00802BE5330A8350A490D4C^%^40AdobeOrg=1; _uetsid=01c1eb4018f811ee9a304164c43be877; _uetvid=851b59f0aca511edbc4f73c5057866b2; MC1=GUID=1dd95f7adb420e35fe1d9f06311e91c3; DUAID=1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3; MC1=GUID=1dd95f7adb420e35fe1d9f06311e91c3; DUAID=1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}


payload = json.dumps({
    "operationName":"PropertyAvailabilityQuery",
    "variables":{"eid":"92311994",
                 "dateRange":{
                     "end":{"day":28,"month":8,"year":2023},
                     "start":{"day":21,"month":8,"year":2023}},
                 "context":{"siteId":9001001,"locale":"en_US","eapid":1,"currency":"USD",
                            "device":{"type":"DESKTOP"},
                            "identity":{"duaid":"1dd95f7a-db42-0e35-fe1d-9f06311e91c3","expUserId":"-1","tuid":"-1","authState":"ANONYMOUS"},
                            "privacyTrackingState":"CAN_TRACK","debugContext":{"abacusOverrides":[],"alterMode":"RELEASED"}
                }},
    "query":"query PropertyAvailabilityQuery($context: ContextInput!, $eid: ID!, $dateRange: DateRangeInput) {\n  propertyAvailabilityCalendars(\n    context: $context\n    eid: $eid\n    dateRange: $dateRange\n  ) {\n    configuration {\n      currentDate {\n        ...DateFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      beginDate {\n        ...DateFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      endDate {\n        ...DateFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      availableByDefault\n      defaultStayConstraints {\n        stayIncrementInDays\n        minimumStayInDays\n        maximumStayInDays\n        __typename\n      }\n      defaultCheckinValidityAfterEndDate\n      defaultCheckoutValidityWhenWithinConstraints\n      __typename\n    }\n    days {\n      date {\n        ...DateFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      available\n      stayConstraints {\n        minimumStayInDays\n        maximumStayInDays\n        stayIncrementInDays\n        __typename\n      }\n      checkinValidity\n      checkoutValidity\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment DateFragment on Date {\n  day\n  month\n  year\n  __typename\n}\n"})
print(payload)

response = requests.post('https://www.vrbo.com/graphql', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response)
data= response.json()
print(data)
```

I get a 200 OK success status response code, but keep getting the following output :

```
{'errors': [{'message': 'Error occurred in downstream service.', 'extensions': {'code': 'DOWNSTREAM_SERVICE_RETURNED_ERROR', 'serviceName': 'experience-api-lodging-availability'}}], 'data': {'propertyAvailabilityCalendars': None}, 'extensions': {'trace': {'Trace-ID': 'fd922130-fae9-47a5-b2f4-73f372fac5fa', 'Message-ID': '00000000-0000-0000-11ec-6582fa9467cb'}}}
```

I tried using different proxies, but keep getting the same error code.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this ?

Comment: This is a custom error from vrbo indicating that your query caused an error in one of the microservices used to resolve your query. This is probably due to an unexpected combination of parameters in the query. Do you have other vrbo queries that are working? How are they different?

Comment: The other one is the following (and it works) :
 json.dumps({
                "operationName": "companyContactForGuest",
                "variables": {
                    "listingId": str(row['triadId'])
                },
                "query": "query companyContactForGuest($listingId: String!) {\n  companyContactForGuest(listingId: $listingId) {\n    companyLabel\n    companyName\n    companyAddressLabels\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"})

Comment: That tells me your basic code is ok but VRBO is having trouble dealing with your specific query. Did you copy it verbatim from a web query or did you compose it yourself?

Comment: I actually tried using POSTMAN, and importing cURL command. It's why I'm not actually sure what is the problem.